# Irrigating the muscles with lubricant blood so it loses less energy to heat

Tags: biology, xenobiology

Having a character that has denser tissues means that heat could be a problem, right?

And because I imagine the human body, after millions of years of evolution, already deals with heat through every way possible and the most efficient way possible, I tried going the other way around and think of ways to produce less heat, mainly during physical exertion and without having to slow the metabolic rate.

So I thought: If the main problem is that the muscles contracting generate heat by attrition, what if the blood irrigating the muscles has some lubricant component that makes it heat less?

Any idea if that could work and/or suggestions?

Comment: "muscles contracting generate heat by attrition" I don't believe attrition is the word you are looking for.  On different note, to my knowledge metabolic rate/activity is where most of the thermal load is coming from for muscle tissue. Shivering for warmth is a thing.

Comment: Converting chemical energy into mechanical energy, in a steam engine, in an internal combustion engine, or in a muscle fiber, is a lossy process; you can never convert all the chemical energy into mechanical energy: some of it will always become waste heat. The way muscles do it, the process has an efficiency of about (optimistically) 30%; that is, about 2 joules of waste heat are generated for every joule of mechanical energy produced. The waste heat generation has nothing to do with lubrication; it is how the engine works.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, lubricating blood wouldn't be useful for humans.  Humans have a closed circulatory system, and the blood doesn't really leave the vessels, except for plasma, which is carried away by the lymphatic system.  It already provides as much lubrication as it needs to without needing to be made *more* lubricating.

The cause of heat generation in humans is not really friction, but metabolic inefficiencies.  Biochemical reactions generate waste heat, and there's no way around it.  The chemical processes in the body are already pretty efficient, and it's unlikely that anything more efficient could be designed, and even if it was, the resultant person wouldn't be human any more.

As the OP said, humans can deal with heat.  In fact, humans are better at dealing with excess heat than pretty much any other land mammal on earth, provided that they stay hydrated to replace water lost through sweating.

So, I wouldn't worry about whatever modifications you've made to your humans generating more heat, I'd worry about your modified humans still *being* human.